# Confused about orthogonality condition and degrees of freedom

Tags: linear-algebra

"Show that the number of constraints that orthogonality conditions for rows and columns impose on an $N \times N$ matrix is $\frac{N( N + 1)}{2}$, so that the number of free parameters is $\frac{N( N - 1)}{2}$."

Please explain what these "free parameters" and "constraints" mean in a matrix? i have looked through similar topics here but i can't understand it completely. i have studied linear Algebra with Khan academy online videos but there wasn't any video related on this. Can anyone direct me to a video that explains this in detail?

I know the orthogonality condition is, $\delta_{jk} = a_{ij} \times a_{jk}$ but how can I use that info to derive the number of constraints?

Comment: Are you aware that you use Einstein summation in your orthogonality condition?

Comment: yes, I'm aware of it.

Comment: Anyway, this condition certainly makes the set of possible matrices smaller starting from the set of all $N\times N$ matrices. It just means you can choose $N(N-1)/2=\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i$  freely, and after you made these choices the other $N(N+1)/2=\sum_{i=1}^{N}i$ are determined by the orthogonality condition. This is what you have to show

Comment: okay but please explain the logic behind it? i know subtracting the number of constraints from n^2 gives the free parameters. but how did we derive the equation for constraints? also can you explain this visually because i have a hard time understanding the logic behind with variables alone.

Comment: can someone explain the logic behind this please?

Answer (score 1):

The formulas are true for orthogonality. For orthonormality, rows have to be rescaled too, which actually imposes $N^2$ constraints: $|a_{i,j}|\leq1$ for all $1\leq i,j\leq N$.

On the first row, you have to choose (at least) one element $a_{1,i_1}$ unequal to zero, otherwise the length of the first row is zero. On the second row, choose at least one $a_{2,i_2}$, $i_1\neq i_2$, unequal to zero, and, given all elements on this row except $a_{2,i_1}$, choose $a_{2,i_1}$ such that the orthogonality condition is satisfied. This imposes one constraint in row $1$, two in row $2$, etc. Apply induction.